# Node.js url module vs Javascript URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, global-object

I was searching for the `URL` module when I found the `URL` on both JavaScript and Node.js.
**I have a few questions:**

1. Is the JavaScript `URL` different from the Node.js URL?
2. What is the difference between the `URL` module in Node.js and the
   features of JavaScript?
3. Inside the documentation was written, the `URL` is known as a global object. So
   you no longer need to require a `url` module?

> Browser-compatible URL class, implemented by following the WHATWG URL
> Standard. Examples of parsed URLs may be found in the Standard itself.
> **The URL class is also available on the global object**.

Inside the global object platform, I also saw the `http`, `path`, `os`, etc. modules.
I wanted to use the `os` and `path` modules without requiring (because they are inside global objects) but my file execution failed:

```
> node test.js
console.log(path); // ReferenceError: path is not defined
```

I also wrote the following code but the undefined value was printed in the output:

```
console.log(global.path); // undefined
```

- what is the reason?

But when I use these in REPL, it returns the following output:

```
<ref *1> {
  resolve: [Function: resolve],
  normalize: [Function: normalize],
  isAbsolute: [Function: isAbsolute],
  join: [Function: join],
  relative: [Function: relative],
  toNamespacedPath: [Function: toNamespacedPath],
  dirname: [Function: dirname],
  basename: [Function: basename],
  extname: [Function: extname],
  format: [Function: bound _format],
  parse: [Function: parse],
  sep: '\\',
  ...
  ...
```

- What is the reason for the difference between REPL and script file?

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The URL object in Node.js is designed to be compatible with the one that you get in browsers.
2. Any visible differences should be mentioned in the docs for the URL class. There do not appear to be any.
3. That is correct - you do not need to `require('url')` if you just want the URL class or URLSearchParams.

You mention some modules being in the global object:

> http, path, os, etc.

However, the documentation does not state that anywhere. On the contrary, these are modules that you need to `require()` yourself. `URL` is documented as being part of the global object, and it's true - it's a class that's available anywhere, much like String, Number, Buffer and some others. This is done for compatibility with the Web platform.

The REPL is special - it includes a usability feature that loads core modules if it sees a reference to them. More details here: https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#accessing-core-nodejs-modules
This means that some code can actually behave differently in the REPL and when run directly via `node`.

Comment: Thank you so much. this is what I want. @Robert Kawecki

Comment: I do not understand your sentence: `The URL object in Node.js is designed to be compatible with the one that you get in browsers.`

Comment: Means the "URL" constructor and the constructed object should behave the same, whether you're using it in Node.js or in a browser such as Chrome, Firefox, etc.